# do sum filtered by year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi want to create some report using data what I have. Below is what I have.

```
Date       Sold
22-Oct-11   22
23-Oct-11   28
24-Oct-11   10
22-Oct-12   22
23-Oct-12   28
24-Oct-12   10
```

What I want is create year and sold total as below.

```
Year   Sold
2011    60
2012    87
```

Any idea how to get this done using excel pre-defined function.

I know this can be done using MACRO, however I don't want to use MACRO.

### Edit 1

I don't want to do this using Pivot too. ONLY Excel pre-defined functions.

Comment: @SeanCheshire : Any version OR atleast Excel 2007 and more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add an extra column for `=Year(date)` then you can use Subtotals to calculate your results (Data-Subtotals)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter in formula window to enter, the curled brackets will be inserted by Excel, not by user):

```
={SUM(IF(YEAR(A1:A4)=2010,1,0)*B1:B4)}
```

Dates are in column A, sold quantities in column B.

Comment: Use a cell reference.
http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/formula_begin_3.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula: `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7;"=*11";$B$2:$B$7)`.
I think it's possible to improve this formula, but I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pivot table. put the date field on the left, right click and Group by year and put the sold field in the values area

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2007 (and later), you have access to the `SUMIFS` function
Assuming your data is in columns A and B, in the order shown, then a function to add up all the data in 2011 would be

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(2011,1,1),A:A,"<="&DATE(2011,12,31))
```

of course, you can reference a cell containing the year number in place of the **2011** to make it portable